# Getting fatal error A1008: unmatched macro nesting in masm when trying to run program

Tags: assembly, x86, masm

I have some assembly code that's trying to add up all the even numbers in an array. But, I keep getting a fatal error when I run it and I can't seem to figure out my mistake. Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD

.data
array BYTE 10,11,13,18,21,23,24,17,45
index BYTE 0
sum BYTE 0
arraySize BYTE ?

.code
main PROC
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF array
    mov arraySize, ecx
    mov esi, 0

L1:        ;for loop
    WHILE:
    cmp esi, ecx
    inc esi
    and array[esi], 1
    jz EVEN
    EVEN: add sum array[esi]
    jl WHILE
LOOP L1

invoke ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP
END main
```

Comment: `WHILE` is a reserved keyword in MASM.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/assembler/masm/while-masm?view=msvc-160.  Just jump to L1; it's at the same address as your `WHILE:` label.  (Then you'll be able to get to later bugs, like mismatched operand-size for `mov arraySize, ecx`, and a missing comma between `add sum, array[esp]`, and the fact that x86 can't use two explicit memory operands for one instruction.  Also, you can use `test` instead of `and`, or just load the byte, mask it, and add the low bit into the total like `reg += array[i] & 1;`)

Comment: This is not a runtime error -- it is a build-time error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`WHILE` is a reserved keyword in MASM. Use `TEST` instead of `AND` to check for evenness. Fixing all of the other bugs and syntax errors (mismatched operands, missing commas etc), the following code works to solve the problem:

```
.386
.model flat, stdcall
.stack 4096
ExitProcess PROTO, dwExitCode:DWORD

.data
array BYTE 10,11,13,18,21,23,24,17,45
sum BYTE 0

.code
main PROC
    mov ecx, LENGTHOF array
    mov esi, -1
    mov al, 0

L1:        ;for loop
    inc esi
    test array[esi], 1
    jnz ODDNUM
    add al, array[esi]
ODDNUM:
    loop L1

    mov sum, al

    invoke ExitProcess, 0
main ENDP
END main
```